# Java - JPanel and/ or its contents not showing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

At the moment I'm trying to implement a `GUI`. Unfortunately I'm only getting a frame with a menuBar. The Panel and its content I defined do not show up.

I would appreciate any advice about why the panel and its content are not shown and what I did wrong (most likely in the `initialiseLeftPanel()` method).

What I have tried so far:

changed the position of `setVisible(true);`

included some `revalidate()`'s;

```
   public class Codebreakerz {
      private static GameRenderer renderer;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      renderer = new GameRenderer();
   }




public class GameRenderer extends JFrame {
    private final String TITLE = "Codebreakerz";
    private Image ICON = getToolkit().getImage("res/confused.png");
    private final int WIDTH = 900;
    private final int HEIGHT = 800;
    private final int ROUNDS = 12;
    private final Color BACKGROUND = Color.lightGray;

    private JPanel left;
    private JPanel right;

    private JLabel attemptsLabel;
    private JLabel correctLabel;
    private JLabel rightNumbLabel;
    private JLabel[] roundLabels;

    public GameRenderer() {
        initialiseWindow();
        initialiseMenu()
        initialiseLabels(); 
        initialiseLeftPanel();          
}

private void initialiseWindow() {
    setTitle(TITLE);
    setIconImage(ICON);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

private void initialiseMenu() {
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("Menu");

    JMenuItem newGame = new JMenuItem("Neues Spiel");
    JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("Schließen");

    file.add(newGame);
    file.add(close);
    menuBar.add(file);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}

private void initialiseLabels() {
    attemptsLabel = new JLabel("0");
    correctLabel = new JLabel("0");
    rightNumbLabel = new JLabel("0");
    roundLabels = new JLabel[ROUNDS];

    for(int i=0; i<ROUNDS; i++) {
        roundLabels[i] = new JLabel();
    }   
}


private void initialiseLeftPanel() {
    left = new JPanel();
    left.setLayout(null); // Tried other stuff aswell   

    JLabel heading = new JLabel("Codebreakerz");
    JLabel tryNr = new JLabel("Anzahl Versuche: ");
    JLabel correct = new JLabel("Richtig: ");
    JLabel correctNumb = new JLabel("Richtige Nummer an falscher Stelle: ");

    left.add(heading);
    left.add(tryNr);
    left.add(correct);
    left.add(correctNumb);

    add(left);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you supress the line `left.setLayout(null);` in your method `initialiseLeftPanel()` and `setLayout(null);` in your method `initialiseWindow()` it will work.

You are obliged to have a Layout if you want display your panels. By default it uses a `FlowLayout`, but here you replaced it by null.

Comment: Your advice worked for me combined with a little change I had to add. I also had to include a panel.setBounds(width, height) instruction to make it show up. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Great, so don't forget to validate the answer, that might help next users